# How to communicate that a tip to staff on a cruise ship is additional to those prepaid?

Tags: cruising, tipping

My wife and I will be traveling on Carnival Cruise lines here in a few days.  We did the prepaid tips.

However I find that two staff members can make a trip extra special.  Those would be the waiter and the steward.

What would be some suggestions about tipping extra to those folks?

How do I communicate that this is an extra tip?  Keep in mind the extra would be low if I did not do the prepaid tips as well.  Keep in mind that many have limited English skills, and that is the only language that I speak.

I was thinking about doing some at the end and some at the beginning.

Comment: Don't over think this :).  You can ask Guest Services for an envelope for the cash.  When you pass the extra gratuity, you can say something like "I did pre-pay, but I want to thank you for a wonderful time."

Comment: Do tip them if they were helpful. From what I have heard and seen on documentaries, they are treated and made to work as donkeys on the cruise liners

Comment: Ummm....no.  Cruise ships are not Roman Triremes.  The crew are treated quite well by the line (better then by the passengers sometimes) and those jobs are substantially better then many in their homeland.

Comment: I think that removing the part on amount suggestion and focusing on the way to tip would make this question fit.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I communicate that this is an extra tip?

Giving money should be perfectly well understood without any *verbal* communication. The donation is *communication*.

The recipient is not going to misunderstand and, say, think you are sending them out to fetch you a pizza.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I ended up doing:

1)  The wait staff on the first night was terrible, luckily we needed a table reassignment.

2)  The next night we were assigned a wonderful wait staff, the got called out in our comments for their great service and I gave the waiter $50 extra at the end of the cruise, and each assistant $20.  Luckily we had them for the rest of the time.

3)  I gave our cabin steward an extra $20 at the end.  He was okay, not great.

Luckily all of the parties involved had great English skills so it was easy to communicate the extra amount.